# Property of hyperbolic rotation matrix with entry 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, rotations, noneuclidean-geometry

I am considering the group of hyperbolic rotation matrices
$G=\{A\in M_{3\times 3}(\mathbb{R}):
A^TDA=D
\}$, where $D=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0\\
0&0&-1\\
\end{bmatrix}$.
It is generated by the following three types of matrices,
namely, the rotations about $x$-axis, $y$-axis and $z$-axis for the hyperboloid
$\mathbb{H}^2:=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}
x\\
y\\
z\\
\end{bmatrix}:
x^2+y^2-z^2=-1, z>0
\right\}$:

$X(\theta)
:=\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0\\
0&\cosh\theta&\sinh\theta\\
0&\sinh\theta&\cosh\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}$,
$Y(\theta)
:=\begin{bmatrix}
\cosh\theta&0&\sinh\theta\\
0&1&0\\
\sinh\theta&0&\cosh\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}$
and
$Z(\theta)
:=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&-\sin\theta&0\\
\sin\theta&\cos\theta&0\\
0&0&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$.

See p.7-8 of [this note](http://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Eweb4520/CG-14-F2017.pdf) for more details.

I am trying to compare this with $SO(3)$.

It is well-known that $A\in SO(3)\iff A^TA=I \iff \langle A x,A y\rangle_{\mathbb
E^3}=\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathbb
E^3}$, where $\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathbb
E^3}=x^Ty$ and $\mathbb{E}^3$ is Euclidean 3-space.

It is also known that $A\in G\iff A^TDA=D \iff \langle Ax,Ay\rangle_{\mathbb
M^3}=\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathbb
M^3}$, where $\langle x,y\rangle_{\mathbb
M^3}=x^TDy$ and $\mathbb{M}^3$ is Minkowski 3-space.

For $A=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\
a_{21}&1&a_{23}\\
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}\in SO(3)$, we have
$\langle\begin{bmatrix}
a_{12}\\
1\\
a_{32}\\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
a_{12}\\
1\\
a_{32}\\
\end{bmatrix}\rangle_{\mathbb{E}^3}
=\langle\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
0\\
1\\
0\\
\end{bmatrix}\rangle_{\mathbb{E}^3}$. Then $a_{12}^2+1+a_{32}^2=1$ and hence $a_{12}=a_{32}=0$.
Since we also have $A^T\in SO(3)$, we can get $a_{21}=a_{23}=0$ by the same reason.
Further argument can show $A=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos\theta&0&\sin\theta\\
0&1&0\\
-\sin\theta&0&\cos\theta\\
\end{bmatrix}$ for some $\theta$, which means $A$ is a rotation about $y$-axis.

> Question 1: Is it the same for $A\in G$?
> Namely, if $A\in G$ and $a_{22}=1$, can we show $A=\begin{bmatrix}
> \cosh\theta&0&\sinh\theta\\
> 0&1&0\\
> \sinh\theta&0&\cosh\theta\\
> \end{bmatrix}$ for some $\theta$? It seems not that trivial to me since I get $a_{12}^2+1-a_{32}^2=1$ instead.

> Question 2: If not, any counterexample?

Comment: No, and you should try to find a counter-example yourself by finding a vector $(x,1,z)$ different from $(0,1,0)$ satisfying the equation $x^2+1-z^2=1$ and then completing it to an orthogonal basis by two more vectors $u, v$, satisfying $(u,u)=1, (v,v)=-1$ (using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization with respect to the Lorentzian bilinear form).

Answer (score 1):

The following matrix is an counterexample:
\begin{bmatrix}
\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& 1&-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}& 1&-\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\
0&-1&\sqrt{2}\\
\end{bmatrix}